# Select value from multivalue text field with selection criteria in same field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with submissions from html forms stored.

The elements and values of the form are each in text formatted columns.

Sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM ftbe2_rsform_submission_values;
+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+------------+
| SubmValId | FormId | SubmId | FieldName    | FieldValue |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+------------+
|         1 |     32 |    460 | date         | 2017-04-17 |
|         2 |     32 |    460 | amount       | 62000      |
|         3 |     32 |    460 | billno       | BE-4587    |
|         4 |     32 |    460 | dispopurchno | 420        |
|         5 |     32 |    460 | price        | 28500      |
|         6 |     32 |    461 | date         |            |
|         7 |     32 |    461 | amount       |            |
|         8 |     32 |    461 | billno       |            |
|         9 |     32 |    461 | dispopurchno | 420        |
|        10 |     32 |    461 | price        | 32000      |
|        11 |     32 |    462 | date         | 2017-04-18 |
|        12 |     32 |    462 | amount       | 62000      |
|        13 |     32 |    462 | billno       |            |
|        14 |     32 |    462 | dispopurchno | 420        |
|        15 |     32 |    462 | price        | 28500      |
|        16 |     32 |    463 | date         | 1995       |
|        17 |     32 |    463 | amount       | 74500      |
|        18 |     32 |    463 | billno       | 42-FOO     |
|        19 |     32 |    463 | dispopurchno | 422        |
|        20 |     32 |    463 | price        | 12000      |
|        21 |     32 |    464 | date         | 2017-04-18 |
|        22 |     32 |    464 | amount       | 510000     |
|        23 |     32 |    464 | billno       |            |
|        24 |     32 |    464 | dispopurchno | 422        |
|        25 |     32 |    464 | price        | 22000      |
|        26 |     32 |    465 | date         |            |
|        27 |     32 |    465 | amount       |            |
|        28 |     32 |    465 | billno       |            |
|        29 |     32 |    465 | dispopurchno | 422        |
|        30 |     32 |    465 | price        | 12000      |
|        31 |     32 |    466 | date         | 2017-04-18 |
|        32 |     32 |    466 | amount       | 31000      |
|        33 |     32 |    466 | billno       |            |
|        34 |     32 |    466 | dispopurchno | 420        |
|        35 |     32 |    466 | price        | 56580      |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+------------+
```

I'd like to select the value of the price, depending on values of rows in the same submission. The desired columns are:

```
FormId, FieldName, FieldValue
```

Desired rows:

```
FormId | FieldName    | FieldValue
-------|--------------|-----------
32     | date         | not empty
32     | amount       | not empty
32     | billno       | empty
32     | dispoburchno | '420' (for example, given by php script)
32     | price        |
```

Desired return:

```
   +------------+
   | FieldValue |
   +------------+
   | 28500      | (SubmId 462)
   | 56580      | (SubmId 466)
   +------------+
```

The query is used in php:

```
$total_price = 0;
$purchno = (from another query)
if ($form->FormId === 32) {
    foreach ($form->submissions as $submission) {
        (execute sql:
            get FieldValue of FieldName[price] from ftbe2_rsform_submission_values where
            SubmissionId = $submisson->SubmissionId
            FieldValue of FieldName[dispopurchno] = $purchno
            FieldValue of FieldName[date] = not empty
            FieldValue of FieldName[amount] = not empty
            FieldValue of FieldName[billno] = empty)
    $totalprice += price;
    }
}
```

I tried with `AND EXISTS`: See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096499/1)
And with `INNER JOIN`: See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096499/3)

What do I miss?
Simon

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I hope it's better now. :)

Comment: date, amount, billno and dispopurchno.

Comment: Sorry, you're rigth of course! The desired rows are FormId, FieldName and FieldValue.

Comment: The laugh was on me. :D. No worries, I'm always confused, what is what. Primary Key is SubmValId. But I'm not sure if this is important in my case.
I added some more details in the question. Does that help better?

Comment: I changed the php usage for this query. I really don't know how to explain my needs better. SubmIndVal is autoincremental.

Comment: You should first make sure your tables are in 3rd normal form. If you run `show create table ftbe2_rsform_submission_values;` what does it give you?

Comment: `show create table ftbe2_rsform_submission_values;`
`CREATE TABLE ftbe2_rsform_submission_values (
 SubmissionValueId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 FormId int(11) NOT NULL,
 SubmissionId int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 FieldName text NOT NULL,
 FieldValue text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (SubmissionValueId),
 KEY FormId (FormId),
 KEY SubmissionId (SubmissionId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7989 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

Comment: @Strawberry I'm sorry, my mistake. corrected.

Comment: Your sample result doesn't match any of the rows in the data set.

Comment: I've written the wrong SubmId for the first desired return. In the submissions with SubmId 462 and 466, FieldName 'date' and FieldName 'amount' have data, FieldName 'billno' hasn't. Both have in FieldName 'dispoburchno' value 420. I'm very sorry about my annoying behaviour! It's a prove, that it's never a good idea to write complex things late in the night. I could understand it if you lose your patience!

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you very much for your patience and your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096499/16/0)

```
SELECT fieldValue
FROM ftbe2_rsform_submission_values A
WHERE exists (SELECT SubMID, count(Distinct FieldName)
              FROM ftbe2_rsform_submission_values B
              WHERE ((fieldName = 'date' and fieldValue <> '')
                 OR (fieldName = 'amount' and fieldValue <> '')
                 OR (fieldName = 'BillNo' and fieldValue = '')
                 OR (fieldName = 'dispopurchno' and fieldValue ='420'))
                AND B.FormID = A.FormID
                AND B.SubmID = A.SubmID
        GROUP BY SUBMID
        having count(distinct fieldName) = 4)
  AND FieldName = 'Price'
```

Subquery makes sure we have a submission with all necessary paired criteria and then we group by the submid ensuring all 4 criteria exist.  we then correlate using an exists to an outer query to get just the price entries for those submissions.

and I hope you have an index on formID, SubmID, fieldname, fieldValue!

As you add additional "paired value mappings" limits you simply increment the 4, or if you reduce a paired mapping you simply reduce the 4; as it seems you would always know how many paired value mappings would exist.

My biggest concerns is the '' vs NULL values potential on the field Value but if we always know it will be empty set '' vs Null then the above should work.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I was looking for! If "billno" has no value, it's an empty string so that will be no problem. Thanks again!

Comment: I might be worried about performance on this in large record count database.  Indexes can help; but only so much.  It may be better to [partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-overview.html) the table by fieldname as the table grows in size.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the manual. For the moment, the subquery is sufficient. As for the next future, the table will not grow too much in size. At most 50 submissions. Old submissions are archived automatically after a month and will be deleted in the actual table.